# CSS Rounded Corner is not working (showing a Gap) on Gmail as Newsletter Template

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Html Newsletter to send it to email service account with Mailchimp Email Newsletter Service provider. So in my newsletter I need a rounded corner on each section. (top and bottom). I know with CSS code it'll not working properly that's why I'm using image. But Still it's not perfect. It's showing a little gap between top rounded image and main section.

**Here is gap on Gmail and Yahoo**

[image]

**Here is my html code:** (You can find the issue on **5th table**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="style/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
    body {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;    
        background-color:#ffffff;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        line-height:150%;
    }
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
#wraper{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
    }
#container{
    width:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
#content{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;  
    width:700px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px solid #666;
    }

#header{
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    clear:both;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wraper">
  <div id="container">
        <div id="content">

<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-bottom:1px #cce6f3 solid; padding-bottom:10px; margin:10px 0;">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/logo.gif" width="188" height="34" alt="Logo" /></td>
    <td align="right" style="padding-right:20px; color:#005699;">June 2014</td>
  </tr>
</table><!--first table-->


<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td style="height:40px; background-color:#f5ec09;"><img src="images/yellow.gif" width="700" height="40" alt="yellow"/></td>
  </tr>  
</table><!--second table-->

<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#faf9e7;">
  <tr>
    <td>




        <table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color:#fff; margin:0 auto 20px auto;">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/banner.gif" width="660" height="135" alt="banner" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:80px; color:#005699; font-size:22px; text-align:center; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Avance 12 Jaar!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0 80px 30px 80px; font-size:12px;">
                <p style="margin-bottom:40px; text-align:justify;">Een moment om terug te kijken op de afgelopen 12 jaar: Op Avance, maar ook zeker op de organisaties en bedrijven die we hebben mogen ondersteunen. Bij deze mooie organisaties horen natuurlijk ook mooie producten. </p>
                <p>Wij hebben een aantal van deze producten verzameld en gaan deze onder jullie verloten. De Avance pagina liken is genoeg om mee te kunnen dingen naar o.a. Taxi tegoed voor Taxi Electric, Heerlijke chocola en koffie van onze projecten in het zuiden en een lunch bij het Bakkerscafé. Facebook <img src="images/arrow.gif" width="16" height="10" alt="arrow" /> naar avance FB 
                <span style="color:#005596;">(https://www.facebook.com/pages/Avance/120374314723870?fref=ts)</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/bottom-rounded.gif" width="660" height="10" alt="bottom-border" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table><!--inner table one-->





<table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin:0 auto 0 auto; padding:0 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><img style="vertical-align:top;" src="images/top-round.gif" width="660" height="11" alt="top-border"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="height:80px; color:#005699; font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; background-color:#fff;">Wat is de<br/> impact van een Social Enterprise?</td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:40px; padding-bottom:30px; background-color:#fff;" valign="top"><img src="images/car.gif" width="261" height="180" alt="car" /></td>
                <td valign="top" style=" background-color:#fff;">
                <p style="font-size:12px; padding-bottom:30px;  text-align:justify;">In samenwerking met Social Enterprise NL en het Anton Jurgens fonds zijn we een traject gestart om de daadwerkelijke impact te meten van Taxi Electric, Bakkerscafé Brood op de Plank en Snappcar. Doel hiervan is impact inzichtelijk maken voor de drie enterprises en duidelijkheid scheppen in de wirwar van impact evaluatiemethodieken. Presentatie van de resultaten op het Avance Social Enterprise Event in oktober. Lees meer <img src="images/arrow.gif" width="16" height="10" alt="arrow" /> <span style="color:#005596;">(http://www.avance-pmc.nl/nl/nieuws/minder-autos-meer-impact)</span></p></td>
            </tr>
</table><!--inner table second-->        
<table style="margin:0 auto ; width:700px; padding:0 20px; margin-bottom:20px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><img src="images/bottom-rounded.gif" width="660" height="10" alt="bottom-rounded" /></td>
</tr>   
</table>   








  </tr>  
</table><!--second table-->




      </div><!--content-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align: bottom` to the image that helps to remove the space.

```
<tr> 
 <td>
  <img style="vertical-align: bottom;" src="images/banner.gif" width="660" height="135"   alt="banner" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where I add this css code ? Something like that ? `<tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><img src="images/banner.gif" width="660" height="135" alt="banner" /></td>
                </tr>`

Comment: No. It should be like this <tr>                     <td><img style="vertical-align: top;" src="images/banner.gif" width="660" height="135" alt="banner" /></td>                 </tr>

Comment: Oh, Ok, I'm trying with this.

Comment: Check if there is height for any parent element.

Comment: I just posted you code in gmail(composed message). vertical-align: top worked at my end.

Comment: I updated my full code again. Please check my update on 5th table.

Comment: Hello Tushar, It's should be `bottom` not `top.` I updated it with 'bottom' and it's working.

Comment: Although, you helped me :) Thanks.